# Facebook Login redirect uri issue in PHP

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, redirect

**f_config.php**

```
<?php
include_once("f_src/facebook.php"); //include facebook SDK
######### Facebook API Configuration ##########
$appId = '<appid>'; //Facebook App ID
$appSecret = '<appsecret>'; // Facebook App Secret
$homeurl = 'http://example.com/login_beta.php';  //return to home
$fbPermissions = 'email';  //Required facebook permissions

//Call Facebook API
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => $appId,
  'secret' => $appSecret

));
$fbuser = $facebook->getUser();
?>
```

**login.php**

```
include_once("f_config.php");

if(!$fbuser){
    $fbuser = null;
    $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('redirect_uri'=>$homeurl,'scope'=>$fbPermissions));
}else{
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me?fields=id,first_name,last_name,email,gender,locale,picture');
    $_SESSION['facebook_data'] = $user_profile; // Storing Facebook User Data in Session
    //var_dump("Asd");
    header("location: index.php");
}
//..
//..

    <?php
          if(!$fbuser){
            $fbuser = null;
           $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('redirect_uri'=>$homeurl,'scope'=>$fbPermissions));
 echo '<a class="btn btn-sm btn-info" href="'.$loginUrl.'"><i class="icon icon-facebook icon-2x"> </i><span style="font-size: 16px; padding: 0 16px;">Continue With Facebook</span></a>';


}

 ?>
```

When I try to logIn with facebook with the developers account it authorizes the app perfectly and lands in index.php
However when I try to login with some other facebook account,it authorizes the app scuuessfully and then redirects back to login.php with code=`<somerandomvalue>` and then again it requires to click facebook login button to redirect to index.php.

I am following this example : http://www.codexworld.com/login-with-facebook-using-php/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to debug and it seems its the url redirection issue with domain including www.
This is typical of redirecting around between url's that have and don't have the www. on them, and causes the session to no longer match the variation of the domain name.

Solution: 
I included the below lines before starting of the session

```
ini_set('session.cookie_domain', '.example.com');
session_set_cookie_params(0, '/', '.example.com');
```

and in .htaccess file added below lines that removes the www form url.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```